# Proof in elementary sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:
$$\text{for all sets } X,Y,Z: X\times(Y-Z) = (X\times Y)-(X\times Z)$$
I was unable to find a counterexample. So I attemped a proof.
I started as follows:
$$X\times (Y-Z) = X\times (Y\cap \bar Z)$$ where $$\bar Z$$ is complement of Z.
Then $$(a,b) \in X\times (Y\cap \bar Z)\space \text{ iff }\space (a\in X) \land (b \in Y \land b\in \bar Z)$$
And I'm stuck... I'd appreciate a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you’re using the usual notation:  $\times$ is the Cartesian product formed by all ordered pairs and $-$ is subtraction (which I’ll denote as $\setminus$).  Then you want to prove this from first principles.  Two sets are equal if each is a subset of the other.

If $(x, w) \in X \times (Y \setminus Z)$, then $x \in X$ and $w \in Y$ but $w\notin Z$, so $(x, w) \in X \times Y$ but $(x, w)\notin X \times Z$, which means $(x, w) \in (X \times Y) \setminus (X\times Z)$.

Can you see how to walk through the converse, that $(X \times Y) \setminus (X \times Z) \subseteq X\times (Y \setminus Z)$?